# Enabling two finger scrolling in Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ast

Tags: touchpad, lenovo-laptop

So I got this new Lenovo laptop it came without any OS. After installing win 10 and the relevant drivers, the TouchPad was not working. Searching on the internet didn't give me anything. Going into the device manager shows that windows recognizes the TouchPad as a mouse, so no two finger scroll or any gesture for that matter. How do I solve this, I couldn't find any compatible drivers on Lenovo website.
Edit : The laptop came with the said TouchPad, Device manager shows it as a generic usb mouse

Comment: Any additional details you give us could be helpful.   For example, is the touchpad original equipment in the Ideapad?  Do you know anything about it (e.g., make and model) other than that?  Exactly what does Device Manager say?